# Why do all quantities used in the formulation of a physical law must be coordinate-invariant?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, materials, solid-mechanics

So I have just started reading the book "*Introduction to Continuum Mechanics_third edition*" written by W. Michael Lai, David Rubin, and Erhard Krempl.

At the end of the book's introduction, the authors stated that **"One important requirement which must be satisfied by all quantities used in the formulation of a physical law is that they be coordinate-invariant."**

I have read about [Principle of Covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_covariance) in Wikipedia. And so I understood, in the example given of newton's 2nd law, how mass, velocity, and force are independent of transformations done between reference frames/ coordinate systems. I have imagined if mass were coordinate-variant, then a body's mass will change if we viewed it from another frame of reference, which is something odd to think about.

But then I thought and asked myself, are there any quantities that are variant when changing a coordinate system, if yes, like what? so this is my first question, and the second, why do all quantities used in the formulation of a physical law must be coordinate-invariant in "Continuum Mechanics" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is why coordinate invariance is mandatory:

Imagine a lab containing a physical system upon which we make measurements in the interests of deriving a physical law. There is a special class of transforms we can apply to the system which leave its dynamics invariant. For each such special transform, called a *symmetry transformation*, there is associated with it a conserved quantity.

In the case of a transform that moves our laboratory across the street, we find that it is a symmetry transform and the conserved quantity is *linear momentum*.

In the case of a transform which rotates the lab around some arbitrary axis, we find that this is also a symmetry transformation and in this case the conserved quantity is *angular momentum*.

In the case of a transform which adds an arbitrary number of seconds to all the stopwatches in the lab that we use to time-stamp our measurements, this too is a symmetry transformation and the conserved quantity is *energy*.

So, for linear momentum to be conserved, our physical law must be coordinate-invariant: it must make no difference where we position our lab in 3-dimensional space, in order to have momentum conservation be a feature of the physical law we are working on.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think with velocities near the speed of light, we might lose the coordinate-invariance property, right?

Comment: Nope, but you have to use general relativity in that case instead of special relativity.

Answer (score 2):

I think the real point of the idea is that "if your model of the physics is not coordinate invariant, it is wrong, because the real world doesn't know anything about coordinate systems."

It is certainly a very useful principle for checking computer software. Set up the same model in two different coordinate systems, and if the results are physically different you have a bug somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the good example :)